# Difference between magento-cloud variable:list and vendor/bin/ece-tools env:config:show

Tags: docker, magento2.4.2, magento-cloud, encryption-key

I'm having issues setting the CRYPT_KEY environment variable in production mode. I can see CRYPT_KEY and env:CRYPT_KEY using the magento-cloud variable:list command, but it isn't recognized when I run docker commands. Inside bin/magento-docker bash, if I run vendor/bin/ece-tools env:config:show, I see the admin email and password that are used to login to the docker container. It looks like ece-tools inside magento-docker bash show the environment variables that are used, and the environment variables from magento-cloud variables:list aren't copied to docker. Would someone be able to explain the difference between these two commands, and how to set CRYPT_KEY inside magento-docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help from Joe Shelton, wagento-joe, on the magento Slack, #cloud-docker channel.

The `magento-cloud` CLI manages Cloud environments. It won't interact with a local environment or docker environment.

The crypt key can be set manually in the env.php file, but it seems that the file was overwritten in [one of the build steps](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-mode-production.html).

To set environment variables locally, use docker-compose.override.yml or .docker/config.env. I used .docker/config.env. [MAGENTO_CLOUD_VARIABLES](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/env/variables-cloud.html) inside .docker/config.env is a base64 encoded json string.

To set a new crypt key:

1. In the Magento instance admin, go to System > Other Settings > Manage Encryption Key
2. Generate a new key and save it for later
3. Decode MAGENTO_CLOUD_VARIABLES in .docker/config.env to get the existing cloud variables
4. Add the crypt key with CRYPT_KEY as the JSON key
5. Encode the JSON and replace the existing MAGENTO_CLOUD_VARIABLES with the encoded JSON string